# PHP regular expression for finding match with two word with some codition

Tags: php, regex

Using this below code I can get the position of word "2Gb" before 5 *letter* of  the word "application". But I want to find the 2Gb before 5 *word* of the word application.

```
<?

$text ="  2Gb existing application While comparing with iPhone and Samsung 
application we can easily say that iPhone has some extra application and features. 
But most of the application in iPhone are now available in Samsung also.
Please look at the below comparison.2Gb with application Apple iPhone 
8Gb with extra application and features Apple iPhone 4Gb with extra application
and features Samsung 8Gb with extra application and features Samsung 
2Gb with extra application and features
";
$regex = '~\b2Gb[a-zA-Z\h]{1,5} application\b~';

if (preg_match_all($regex, $text, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
print_r($matches[0]);
}


?>
```

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
$regex = '~\b2Gb (?:\w+\s+){5}application\b~';
```

This count exactly 5 word between `2Gb` and `application`, if you want **at most** 5 words, use:

```
$regex = '~\b2Gb (?:\w+\s+){0,5}application\b~';
```

Comment: i think you failed to add space after 2GB in your regex.

Comment: [Have a look at this](http://regex101.com/r/nR0iG6) . And i think he wants atmost 5 word characters after `2GB` followed by a space.

Comment: @user3627649: Glad it helps. Feel free to accept the answer.